# Как обработать клавишу enter при вводе текста в EditText android

Tags: android, java

Есть EditText, нужно выполнять какие-то события, когда пользователь нажал Enter.

Answer (score 6):

1. Создать класс, наследующийся от
       EditText;
2. В этом классе переопределить метод onKeyUp или onKeyDown, зависит от того, нужно ли полностью перекрыть дефолтную функциональность Enter;
3. В переопределенном методе написать что-то вроде следующего:

   public boolean onKeyUp (int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

   ```
   if (keyCode == KEYCODE_ENTER) {
       //Делаем то, что нам нужно...
   } else {
       super.onKeyUp();
   }
   ```

   }

Вариант без наследования класса:

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit);
editText.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        boolean consumed = false;
        if (keyCode == KEYCODE_ENTER) {
            //Делаем то, что нам нужно...
            consumed = true; //это если не хотим, чтобы нажатая кнопка обрабатывалась дальше видом, иначе нужно оставить false
        }
        return consumed;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно и не создавать своего класса-наследника от EditText. Достаточно к существующему виджету навесить нужный (onKeyUp) лисенер